# Pandas index if statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to make a new column of 1's if the index is greater than x in a pandas dataframe.

But this code isn't working. Anyone have any ideas?

```
if df.index>=3:
    df['Step1']=1
else:
    df['Step1']=0
```

Comment: here you are checking for entire df. may be you should do that for each element

Comment: Can you show more of your code and the error you receive?

Comment: yes so the dataframe index is 0 to 100. And if greater than 3, I wanted a new column to = 1

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: thats all the code I have really. Its just a dataframe I've loaded in from a csv

Comment: @fred.schwartz, i answered your question, does that help?, i used a sample dataframe. you can replace it with your dataframe read from a csv

Comment: @InAFlash yes that is just what I was after. Thanks alot. Really helpful

Comment: @InAFlash how can I do this but inbetween instead of greater than? df.index>4 and df.index<8

Comment: @fred.schwartz, updated the answer, take a look

Comment: @InAFlash great thanks alot. Very useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lets take an example `dataframe` as below

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4,5],"b":[2,4,9,16,25]})
```

index method prints as below

```
In [4]: df.index
Out[4]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)
```

and `df.index >3` prints as below

```
In [5]: df.index>3
Out[5]: array([False, False, False, False,  True])
```

so, answer is

```
y = df.index>3
df['new_column'] = y.astype(int)
df
   a   b  new_column
0  1   2    0
1  2   4    0
2  3   9    0
3  4  16    0
4  5  25    1
```

Edit:
if you want to do between 3 and 9 indexes
you do the following

```
import numpy as np
np.logical_and(df.index>2, df.index<5)
array([False, False, False,  True,  True])
```